# C# get Console.Writeline(" ") to speak (" ")

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
case "Start VS":
    Console.WriteLine("Starting Visual Studio's...");
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("devenv.exe");
    break;
```

How might I be able to get a soundclip to play, using the string input? ("Starting Visual Studio"...)

Comment: aaaand what is the question?

Comment: @Ben to have Console.WriteLine (" ") to Speak what's inside.

Comment: So you want it to literally *say* "Starting Visual Studio"? Like out of the speakers??

Comment: @Ben Yeah, I cant find how to do it anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer` class. Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the example and additional info.

Comment: [That's a thing...](https://wtfbabe.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/kingsman-23-gif-minds-blown-wtf-watch-the-film-saint-pauly.gif)? I thought you were being sarcastic...